# What is the Exact Layout to use SwipeRefreshLayout in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using a `Fragment` to display `WebView` while implementing `onLongClick()` to download images and `SwipeRefreshLayout`.
My issue is that when I use `SwipeRefreshLayout` with `ScrollView` & `Webview` in it, I can't download Images.

I tried this:

`SwipeRefreshLayout` >
`ScrollView` >
`CoordinatorLayout` >
`Webview`

Is this layout right?

Comment: I think you should add a down gesture listener to the web view. Search it.

Comment: @AawazGyawali is the layout format right?